# discord.js v13 previous button auto hide after new interaction

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I made a command called facts so whenever a type /facts it give the facts and there is button called More facts so when a user clicked more facts it gives anothers facts embed. Preview https://postimg.cc/ft0smLKf

So i want to make it like this when a user click More facts it give the new facts embed the previous embed button will be hide. here is an example: https://streamable.com/i88xxr

```
if(commandName === 'facts'){
      try{
        const factsRow = new MessageActionRow()
          .addComponents(
            new MessageButton()
              .setLabel('More Facts')
              .setStyle('PRIMARY')
              .setCustomId('facts1')
            )
            .addComponents(
              new MessageButton()
              .setURL('https://top.gg/bot/874488895037911041/vote')
              .setLabel('Vote Us')
              .setStyle('LINK')
            )
         
        const mavlina = new Mavlina()
        const factsd = await mavlina.facts()
         // embed
         const factsEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
         .setColor('#111133')
         .setTitle("Facts")
         .setDescription(`${factsd.data}`)

       // sending reply
       interaction.reply({
        components: [factsRow],
         embeds: [ factsEmbed ]
       })
       
       const colllector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector();

       colllector.on('collect', async (i) => { 
        const mavlina = new Mavlina()
        const factbtn = await mavlina.facts()
         // embed
         const factsbtnEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
         .setColor('#111133')
         .setTitle("Facts")
         .setDescription(`${factbtn.data}`)
        await i.reply({ embeds: [factsbtnEmbed],  components: [factsRow] })
       })
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message)
      }
   }
```

So i want to make it like this when a user click More facts it give the new facts embed the previous embed button will be hide. here is an example: https://streamable.com/i88xxr

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the embed, but instead of inserting the buttons, you will make them not exist, putting only []

```
  await i.update({ embeds: [factsbtnEmbed], components: [] })
```

I hope to be of help to you.

Comment: @1ly4so so the reply line still be there right?

Comment: it give me a error 

if (!this.deferred && !this.replied) throw new Error('INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED');
^
Error [INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED]: The reply to this interaction has not been sent or deferred.
at ButtonInteraction.editReply (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:136:48)
at InteractionCollector.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:380:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
[Symbol(code)]: 'INTERACTION_NOT_REPLIED'
}

Comment: copy it again, it would be working now

Comment: its `i.update` not `i.edit` (https://v13.discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#updating-the-button-message)